# Urn Problem and Cartesian Product of Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, integer-partitions

Consider a Graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$ where each node $v\in V$ has a label $l_v\in\{1,...,n\}$. Denote by $G^k$ the k-fold Cartesian product of $G$ with itself where $k<n$. The set of nodes is consequently $V^k$. Denote by $D_l = \{w\in V^k|\exists i_1,...,i_l\in\{1,...,n\},\; i_1\neq...\neq i_l: w_{i_1}=w_{i_2}=..w_{i_l}\text{ and }l\text{ is maximal}\}$   for $l\in\{1,...,k\}$. I am wondering about the size of $D_l$ as a function of $l,k,n$.

I approached the problem by looking at each $w\in V^k$ as a vector of $k$ colored balls and if $w\in D_l$ the largest proportion of one color has size $l$. Hence the partition function $p(k,l)$ gives me all possibilities to color the nodes. But then I am stuck because I do not see how to combine the possible permutations of colors and choosing $k$ colors out of $n$ (with replacement).

How can I approach this?
I used the tag "integer-partitions" because of the link to the partition function.

Comment: I don't understand how the graph enters into all this. Aren't you just taking about the $k$-fold Cartesian power of $V$? Nothing seems to depend on the edges.

Comment: That is correct, afterwards in a final Graph $H=(V^k, E_H)$ the edges exist only between notes which are within the same $D_l$ and I want to find something out about the degrees within each $D_l$. I wasn't sure whether to put the whole question...

Comment: This is a hard problem; I doubt you'll find a closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say your function is $f(l,k,n)$; we have $l < k < n$.

If I understand correctly, then $f(l,k,n) = n \binom{k}{l} (n-1)^{k-l}$ if $l \geq \frac{k}{2}$, right?  Because we're looking for the number of $k$-tuples with $l$ entries all equal to one of $n$ elements, and the other $k - l$ entries all chosen from the other $n-1$ possibilities.

If $l < \frac{k}{2}$, then we have to worry about not allowing more than $l$ of the other entries to be equal. One way to do it is by exclusion:

$$
f(l,k,n) = n \binom{k}{l} (n-1)^{k-l} - n \binom{k}{l} (n-1) \binom{k-l}{l+1} (n-2)^{k-2l-1} - \dotsb - n \binom{k}{l} (n-1) \binom{k-l}{l+(k-2l)}
$$

But actually, if $l < \frac{k}{3}$, you have to worry about more possibilities, so this seems like a pain.

Let's see. We want permutations of $k$ out of $n$ things with at most $l$ repetitions, where at least one thing does repeat $l$ times.
Roberto Frucht called the number of arrangements with at most $l$ repetitions $P(n,k,l)$ in [Permutations with limited repetitions](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(66)80025-X), giving several formulas for it there.
A recursive definition which is supposed to be more computationally efficient is given in [On permutations with limited repetition](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(81)90034-0) by H Mendelson.

With this, we only have to remove those tuples which don't have any elements repeated $l$ times, hence actually have at most $l-1$ repetitions. So

$$
f(l,k,n) = P(n,k,l) - P(n,k,l-1).
$$

Comment: The permutation with limited repetitions source is really a goldmine in this context. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just have a small problem that $\sum_{l=1}^k f(l,k,n)=n^k$ since $V^k$ has size $n^k$ if $V$ has size $n$. But if I do the sum using the recurrence by Mendelson I do not get the same result. (Test for n=10, k = 4, hence $|V^k|=10.000$ but I obtain $\sum_{l=1}^k f(l,k,n)=25.390$ ...

Comment: @Jfischer: Oh yeah, there's still overcounting. The $n \binom{k}{l}$ part is to guarantee that there are $l$ repeated elements, since $P(n,k,l)$ only counts tuples with at most $l$ repeats of each, but if more than one number has $l$ repeats, it'll be counted twice. I think it's easy to fix (see edit)

Comment: Thank you! I figured that this would be sufficient. If I could, I would upvote your answer multiple times!!! Knowing about the two papers helps me a lot!

Comment: @NickMatteo Hi, would it be possible if you can help with some graph theory problems? Like in a room chat or something? I just have many problems, and instead of posting for each on stackoverflow, and you answer regardless here, I thought you may help this way, as I checked the users and found you good at discrete mathematics,